# Save and display comment in real-time using angularjs and socket.io

Tags: angularjs, express, mongoose, socket.io

I have problem with `socket.io`. In my code `router.post(/comment,...)` saving user comments in database (using mongoose) and I am trying `emit` this save. In controller function `readMoreCourse` is to get and display all comments from database (and question how use socket to this function that using ng-reapat display comment in real-time). Function `AddComment` is on client side chceck valid form and next post comment to database. 
My question: How in real-time save and display user comment using angular (ng-repeat?) and socket.io? Honestly I making this first time, and I have short time, thanks for any help.

Server

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('comment', function(){
    console.log('Comment emitted')
  })
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  })
})
```

API

```
router.post('/comment', function(req, res) {  
    Product.findOne({ _id: req.body._id }, function(err, product){  
        if(err) {
           res.json({ success:false, message: 'Course not found' })
        } else { 
           User.findOne({ username: req.decoded.username }, function(err, user){   
            if(err){
               res.json({ success:false, message: 'Error'})
             } else { 
                product.comments.push({
                    body: req.body.comment,
                    author: user.username,
                    date: new Date(),   
                 });
                 product.save(function(err){
                    if(err) throw err 
                    res.json({ success: true, message: 'Comment added })
                    **io.emit('comment', msg);**
                  })        
               } 
             })                                        
          }
      }) 
 })
```

controller

```
Socket.connect();  

User.readMoreCourse($routeParams.id).then(function(data){
    if(data.data.success){
        app.comments = data.data.product.comments;
    } else {
        $window.location.assign('/404');
    }
});         
    app.AddComment = function(comment, valid) {     
        if(valid){
            var userComment = {}; 
            userComment.comment = app.comment;
            Socket.on('comment', User.postComment(userComment).then(function(data){  
                if(data.data.success){ 
                    $timeout(function(){
                        $scope.seeMore.comment = '';
                    },2000)
                } else {
                    app.errorMsg = data.data.message;
                }    
            }));    
        } else {
            app.errorMsg = 'Error';
        }
    }       
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event){
    Socket.disconnect(true);
})
```

factory

```
userFactory.readMoreCourse = function(id) {
    return $http.get('/api/seeMore/' + id) 
}
userFactory.postComment = function(comment){
    return $http.post('/api/comment', comment);  
}

.factory('Socket', function(socketFactory){
   return socketFactory()
})
```

Comment: does the controller code `Socket.on` work?

Comment: Basically if I remove socket part this code works fine, everything is proper saveing to databse, but now doesn't work. In controller not working, but in factory e.g. console,log displays messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your socket factory, initialize socket.io `emit` and `on` events.

```
app.factory('socket', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  var socket = io.connect();

  return {
    on: function(eventName, callback){
      socket.on(eventName, callback);
    },
    emit: function(eventName, data) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data);
    }
  };
}]);
```

and call this from controller

```
app.controller('yourController', function($scope, socket) {     

User.postComment(userComment).then(function(data){  
  if(data.data.success){ 
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.seeMore.comment = '';
      },2000); 

    // Emit new comment to socket.io server 
    socket.emit("new comment", userComment);

  } else {
      app.errorMsg = data.data.message;
  }
 });

 // other clients will listen to new events here 
 socket.on('newComment', function(data) {
     console.log(data);
     // push the data.comments to your $scope.comments    
 });
```

from socket.io server

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  // listen for new comments from controller and emit it to other clients 
  socket.on('new comment', function(data) {
    io.emit('newComment', {
      comment: data
    });
  });
});
```

EDIT: 
If you just want to push from server side,

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    // after saving your comment to database emit it to all clients 
    io.emit('newComment', {
      comment: data
    });
});
```

and remove this emit code from controller:

```
socket.emit("new comment", userComment);
```

But this method can be tricky because the user who posts the comment should immediately see the comment added to the post. If you let `socket.io` to handle this there will be a few seconds lag for the guy who posted the comment.

Comment: Thank you for help, but I have question to tour code. Can I use socket.on('newComment', ...) in my API with product save? i.g. is possible in one time save to database and other clients can listen new event ?

Comment: yes, you can do that. Just don't emit from client side and push new comments from server side. Updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks I will try do it :) so I understand that if I emit from server side my ng-repeat with comments will automatically update if database will change

Comment: aaa ok, so if use $scope.comment =[ ] in client side this prevent the few scecond lag

Comment: cool try that :) the comment might be added twice because from server we are pushing to all clients.

Comment: Srikanth Jeeva could you explain me what is comment:data in server side ?

Comment: It was just for reference. in this case, the data in the comment that you want to broadcast to all clients. `comment` is just the name given to the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154266/discussion-between-v-r-and-srikanth-jeeva).

Comment: I think last question, because something is wrong. In controller socket.on('newComment'...) console.log(data) display weird array. e.g. first comment is 'aaaa', second comment is 'bbb', 'bbb', third 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc' etc. but if I take console log(userComment) works good third comment is 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'. Do you know what is this happen?